# inputs are not considered in form validation when using ng-content

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-ngcontent

Given the following component (with selector my-template):

```
<form #theForm="ngForm">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</form>
```

and use it like this:

```
<my-template>
    <input type="text" required name="firstName" [(ngModel)]="firstName"/>
</my-template>
```

The form is always valid - even though the input is invalid. How can I make this work so that the form is invalid when the input is invalid?

Live demo:
https://plnkr.co/edit/lWUe6oeBk6ccsE2JxNKb?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Just for test purposes, try to change your form template to:

```
<form #theForm="ngForm">
    <input type="text" required name="lastName" [(ngModel)]="lastName"/>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</form>
```

You will see, that form becomes invalid when `lastName` is invalid. Which means that `FormComponent` processes own HTML elements fields before `ng-content` is rendered. I.e. you have to update `FormControl`s after template is rendered.

Please read this topic [Dynamic Form](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-form.html) for more information